# Read JSON (text file) into .NET application

Tags: c#, json

I have a configuration file in the following JSON format:

```
{

  "key1": "value1",  
  "key2": "value2",  
  "key3": false,  
  "key4": 10,  

}
```

The user can set/unset the configuration values using a text editor. I however need to read it in my C# application. Whats the best way to do so for JSON? The above keys are not associated with a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Json.NET: http://json.codeplex.com

Comment: I took a look at it earlier. It recommends using LINQ - but was not sure how to go about using it. My configuration file is in the form of a text file!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work for you?

```
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = @"{
                          'key1': 'value1',  
                          'key2': 'value2',  
                          'key3': false,  
                          'key4': 10
                        }";
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json); // deserialize

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> o in dic)
        {
            // do whatever
        }


        dic.Add("newKey", "new value"); // add an attribute

        string newjson = js.Serialize(dic);  // serialize back to string
```

Comment: I have a json array like [{'key1': 'value1' , 'key2': 'value2'},{'key1': 'value1' , 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value1' , 'key2': 'value2'}] How to convert that.Can you pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can have a look at the [JSONReaderWriterFactory from the .Net 3.5SP1 stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.aspx).