# Need help to parse JSON file

Tags: json.net

It is my first time to coding relate JSON file. I download the using Newtonsoft.Json. I read the document on Json.Net, but I still cannot figure out how to retreive the data in my Json file. Hope someone can help me. My question is how can I pull the Discount information by using Querying JSON with LINQ? Thanks in advance.

There is the Json file.

```
{"id":"id2356T14-Mar-2013",
 "date":"14-Mar-2013",
 "productInfo":[{"packing":"box",  "Qty":"36 dozen",
 "Discount":[{"Qty":"50 dozen", "percentage":"1"},
                   {"Qty":"100 dozen", "percentage":"2"}    ]
   }

 }
```

Comment: Incorrect bracketing detected, or an incomplete JSON.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640530/read-json-text-file-into-net-application ?

Comment: @SteveP it is not same question. My json file is complicated that I cannot figure out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**C# Classes:**

```
public class Discount
{
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string percentage { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInfo
{
    public string packing { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public List<Discount> Discount { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInfo> productInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do you know what can use Querying JSON with LINQ to pull the data for my file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is incomplete. It needs a trailing ] and } to close it properly.

```
{"id":"id2356T14-Mar-2013",
 "date":"14-Mar-2013",
 "productInfo":[{
   "packing":"box",  "Qty":"36 dozen",                     
   "Discount":[{"Qty":"50 dozen", "percentage":"1"},
              {"Qty":"100 dozen", "percentage":"2"}]
  }] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you read your first `Qty` and `percentage` value

```
JObject myObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
foreach(var resource in myObj["Discount"])
{
    var props = resource.Children<JObject>().First();
    Console.WriteLine(props["Qty"] + " " + props["percentage"]);
}
```